# Отличия между получением значения из Extras

Tags: android, android-intent

Обратил внимание, что есть три способа получения значения из `Extras`:

```
    someInt = getIntent().getIntExtra("KEY", 0);
    someInt = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("KEY");
    someInt = (int) getIntent().getExtras().get("KEY");
```

Чем принципиально отличаются эти способы? Если в последнем можно получить что угодно и тут различие еще понятно, то какое различие между первым и вторым способом?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если зайти и посмотреть исходники то можно увидеть следующий код:

```
public int getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue) {
    return mExtras == null ? defaultValue :
        mExtras.getInt(name, defaultValue);
}

public Bundle getExtras() {
    return (mExtras != null)
            ? new Bundle(mExtras)
            : null;
}
```

Оба элемента работают с объектом `mExtra`, тип которого `Bundle`. Первый вариант вернет дефолтное значение если этот объект не установлен, а второй копию объекта `mExtra`.

У объекта `Bundle` метод `getInt(String key, int defaultValue)` имеет следующую релизацию

```
public int getInt(String key, int defaultValue) {
    unparcel();
    Object o = mMap.get(key);
    if (o == null) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    try {
        return (Integer) o;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        typeWarning(key, o, "Integer", defaultValue, e);
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

а метод `get(String key)` следующую:

```
@Nullable
public Object get(String key) {
    unparcel();
    return mMap.get(key);
}
```

Оба они работают с объектом `mMap`, только первый метод сразу преобразует результат в `int` либо вернет дефолтное значение, в то время, как второй возвращает тип `Object`, который придется кастовать вручную.

Исходя из реализации данных методов видно, что метод `getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue)` является "шорткатом" относительно других методов. Так же он более безопасен, т.к. вы не получите `NullPointerException` либо `ClassCastException`